# Using Facebook Connect SDK for my iPhone app

Tags: iphone, facebook

Okay, I am using Cocos2d for developing an Iphone game, and I wish to implement Facebook Connect.

I found a tutorial about integrating Facebook Connect in the Cocos2d forums (http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/3392), but the link it provides for downloading the Facebook SDK is... broken. And I have no idea where to actually download it! Every link I find in Google seems to have been removed from Facebook's documentation. And that tutorial is a bit old... is there any updated content about such? Can someone guide me as to where should I get started? (downloading the SDK)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook seems to be notoriously bad for dropping support or unlinking features. Try:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#ios